# Context.User always null with basic authentication in ASP.NET vNext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm working on writing a simple login page + SignalR chat room for my website with vNext `beta8`.  Unfortunately, I'm having a very difficult time understanding how claims and authentication work.

All I am trying to do is authenticate a user and set `Context.User` to their identity, so it can be accessed in SignalR.  With the way I have it now, though, `Context.User` is null everywhere, so SignalR isn't even the meat of this question.

Here's the relevant bits of code for this issue:

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSession();
    services.AddCaching();
    services.AddSignalR();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
    });
    app.UseSignalR();
}
```

**Login Web API controller method** with default values provided, skipping password/authentication checks, and setting the session, which works.  `LoginUserInfo` is just a small class to receive a username/password for logging in.

```
[HttpPost]
public string Login(LoginUserInfo info)
{
    kUser user = new kUser();
    user.Name = "Test user";

    //This is where I am completely missing the point of something
    Context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(user);
}
```

**kUser** - this class is incomplete, I'm assuming that `AuthenticationType` and `IsAuthenticated` don't come into affect here, since the exception is never thrown.

```
[Serializable]
public class kUser : IIdentity
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string AuthenticationType
    {
        get { return "MongoDB"; }
    }

    public bool IsAuthenticated
    {
        get
        {
            //If ID exists in database
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Research leads me to many different ways to accomplish setting `Context.User` and having it available across the entire application.  Some guides point to `FormsAuthentication`, which doesn't seem to exist in ASP.NET 5, some talk about setting user IDs to each thread, and some detail how to write an entire service provider for authentication.

All I want is an extremely basic login procedure - no Remember Me style cookies, nothing fancy.  Just type in username/password, and the server remembers you for your session.  Where am I going wrong, and what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like this

```
var claims = new[] { new Claim("name", authUser.Username), new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin") };
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
Context.Authentication.SignIn(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
```

More details - https://github.com/anuraj/CookieAuthMVCSample

I didn't verified the code with latest runtime.

Comment: This works perfectly, and thank you very much for the example!

Comment: Just for future reference, `Context.Authentication.SignIn` has been replaced with `Context.Authentication.SignInAsync`, but it's used in the same way as this example.

Comment: True, I didn't verified the code with latest runtime.